# C two dimensional array input

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

My code for inputing pairs of numbers,inputs numbers in strange order,can't figure out whats wrong.I added aditional for loop to look at inputed values.n is the number of pairs user should enter.

```
    int main(){   int i,j,n,pairs[100][1];
printf("Select the number of pairs you want to enter(no more than 100):");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter the pairs:");
for(i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
for( j=0; j<2; j++ ) {
   scanf("%d", &pairs[i][j]);
}
}
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
   printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, pairs[i][j] );
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Lets say i choose the number of pairs 2,then i input 4space6enter 7space9enter,my array should look like:

```
    pairs[0][0]=4
    pairs[0][1]=6
    pairs[1][0]=7
    pairs[1][1]=9
```

But now i get:

```
    pairs[0][0]=4
    pairs[0][1]=7
    pairs[1][0]=7
    pairs[1][1]=9
```

Comment: What is `pairs`? What is `n`? What is the value of `n`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Showing how you declared your variables, *and* the full input you provided,  would also be helpful.  If I declare the variables how I think they should be declared, *and* provide input as I think it should be, I get the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int pairs[100][1];`

A "pair" usually requires two elements.  Try

`int pairs[100][2];`

Comment: Yeah it fixed the problem,thanks! I just don't get it aren't arrays numbered from 0 so the 1 element would be the second one and two places should be enough for a pair to store?

Comment: int pairs[100][2] defines an array of 100 items numbered 0 through 99, each being an array of 2 items numbered 0 through 1.

Comment: Accepting the answer is the standard way of thanking people, if you please.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to have problems with 2D arrays, use an intermediate variable:

```
int a;
for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
    for( j=0; j<2; j++ ) {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        a=poros[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it at first but then i thought why adding and aditional variable,and went this way,still doesn't change my problem,i get the same wrong output.